# How to change custom button's text?

Tags: ios, uibutton

I need to set text to the this custom button.I thought it would be as easy as using `setText` method to set its text. But, unfortunately, it doesn't work.

So, why this approach doesn't work  for any **custom buttons**?

When  we changed its type to **custom**, basically how it effects this `UIButton`?

Thank you.

**EDIT:** I've created this **UIButton** through IB. The code used for changing text is this :

```
  [self.btnDiscover setTitle:@"Discover" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

[image: A Custom Button]

Comment: I think Custom Button background Color and Text Color are same thats why Text can't be visible. 
Try to change the text Color and then write text on that buttom.

Please provide code also for the same

Comment: I've already tried it. I've set different colors for background and text color and didn't work.

Comment: try to use :
 [btnObject setTitle:@"TextName" forState:UIControlStateNormal];

Comment: I'm betting self.btnDiscover is nil because you've hooked things up wrong. Hence nothing is happening.

Comment: Please provide some block of code to change text of custom button.

Comment: @matt,i'm pretty sure it's not nil,here is console output for btnDiscover

(UIButton *) $0 = 0x1e5a2ee0 <UIButton: 0x1e5a2ee0; frame = (0 278; 320 44); opaque = NO; autoresize = RM+BM; layer = <CALayer: 0x1e5a2fd0>>

Comment: Oh no, I'm losing my bet! :) Could you explain more about how this button is acquiring its image, then (as shown in your picture)? Also, your image is not 320 pixels wide, but your button is; are you sure that picture *is* your button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `setTitle:forState:` instead of `setText`, e.g.:

```
[button setTitle:NSLocalizedString(@"CONTACT_BUTTON", @"Contact Us") forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

Also, make sure you are using `setBackgroundImage:forState:` to set the button image and not `setImage:forState:`.

As to your question about the custom style, assigning `UIButtonTypeCustom` to a button simply means that the button is assigned no style ([source](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UIButton_Class/UIButton/UIButton.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIButtonType)):

> UIButtonTypeCustom
>
> No button style.

Comment: strange, I checked the code in a project of mine where I use custom buttons and set the title like that... your problem must be elsewhere...

Comment: I also do the same in one of my projects

Comment: @sergio,is there any image you set for button image ?

Comment: yes, I use an image and show the title on top of it. the image is set with `– setBackgroundImage:forState:`. are you using `setImage:forState:` maybe?

Comment: That was the issue.Thank you.